# How to make a ChartKick line chart with Rails associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chartkick

I'm struggling with formatting my ruby code to get the kind of chart I want.  I'm making a Rails 6 app with a few layers of associations between tables.
I have:

- Each Headline has_one Article
- Each Article has_one Sentiment
- Sentiment table has a score column

The Chart I want to build will simply be X-axis = Headline.created_at, Y-axis headline.article.sentiment.score

CONTROLLER

```
@headlines = Headline.where("created_at = ?", Date.today)
```

VIEW CODE

```
<%= line_chart @headlines.group_by_day(:created_at).count %>
```

How do I get the Y-Axis to be 'score' instead of 'count'?

THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you did setup the relationships of your models. If you have a relationship in `Headline` to `Sentiment` like this

```rb
class Headline
  has_one :article
  has_one :sentiment, through: :article
end
```

You can simply do something like this

```rb
@headlines.each_with_object({}) do |headline, result|
  result[headline.id] = headline.sentiment&.score
end
# { 1: 2, 3: 4}
```

You should include the `article` and `sentiment` in your initial query otherwise you will have a [n+1 query](https://blog.appsignal.com/2018/04/24/active-record-performance-the-n-1-queries-antipattern.html) like this

```rb
Headline.includes(:article, :sentiment).where("created_at = ?", Date.today)
```

There is probably a more performant way to group inline in SQL but this should do.